# Delay in gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Currently I'm working true ftp and running gulp watch on te server, now te problem is that when my gulp watch is detecting changes the file is not ready with uploading, so I need to have a delay in my gulp watch.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    gulp.watch(config.js.app.pathIn + '/**/*.js', ['js_app']);
    gulp.watch(config.js.vendor.pathIn + '/**/*.js', ['js_vendor']);
    gulp.watch(config.scss.pathIn + '/**/*.scss', ['scss']);
  }, 3000);
});
```

This is not delaying the rendering of the files, how can I make sure to have a delay when rending the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gulp-wait](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wait) looks like it could work for you.  Insert it into the top of your three tasks.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch(config.js.app.pathIn + '/**/*.js', setTimeout(function() {
     gulp.start('scss')
  }, 3000)
});
```

Above **might** work if you want a setTimeout method but it uses gulp.start - to be removed from gulp4.0.  Much easier if you used gulp4 and just made a function call here to your task instead of to gulp.start.

But I suggest gulp-wait.

Answer (score 8):

In Gulp 4, `gulp.watch` accepts an options object which, among other things, can [define a `delay`](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-watcher#optionsdelay):

```
gulp.watch( someGlob, { delay: 500 }, someTask );
```

---

The fine print:

The delay only works for a task function which is passed as an argument to `gulp.watch`. It does have any effect on event handlers which are set on the return value of `gulp.watch`. In other words, a `delay` set in the options for

```
gulp.watch( globs, options, taskFunction );
```

works, but

```
let watcher = gulp.watch( globs, options ); 
watcher.on( "change", callback );
```

ignores `options.delay`.

That's because `gulp.watch` returns an instance of [`chokidar`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar), which doesn't know about options which are specific to `gulp.watch` (such as `delay` or `queue`).

If you need a delay for event-specific watch tasks, set it up with the `events` option instead:

```
gulp.watch( globs, { events: ["add", "change"], delay: 500 }, taskFunction );
```

The `event` option is currently missing [in the Gulp 4 docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#opts) but you'll find it in the [documentation of `glob-watcher`](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-watcher#optionsevents), the component providing the watch functionality.